# Understanding the code logic of Calendar PHP

Tags: php

Can someone help me understand the logic of this loop. I am new to php and making a calendar from tutorial. The logic of this if Condition is unclear to me. Here is the code

```
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
```

The hardest line to decrypt is:

```
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which line and what part you dont understand.

Comment: The second if condition, is harder to decrypt. When this nested if condition is true, i don't understand what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
        $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
    endif;
```

Its actually creating a new row in your table when after adding 1 to day counter variable not equal to days in month variable.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So the <tr class= "calendar-row"> is adding a new row!

Comment: thanks, alot. Now i really understand and can control behaviour of my calendar